# Android Share Intent EXTRA_STREAM

Tags: android, android-intent, share

I have this method that shares a textfile or a picture depending of which EXTRA_STREAM I'm using. I have these two I can choose from

```
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
```

How can I share both at the same time when I call startActivity?

Here is my code

```
public void shareTextAndPic(){
    
    long x = getBundle();

    Product product = db.findProductbyId(getBundle());
    

    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(db.fetchSingle(x), 0,
            db.fetchSingle(x).length);
    
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("image/jpeg");

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Images.Media.TITLE, "title");
    values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
    Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            values);


    OutputStream outstream;
    try {
        outstream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
        icon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outstream);
        outstream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.toString());
    }

    //share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    //startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
    
    
    File file = new File(way + "/momsfil.txt");
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.setType("text/plain");
    i.setType("image/jpeg");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "ttj@live.se" });
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "body of email");
    
    
    //i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    
    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share"));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(TableRow.this,
                "There are no email clients installed.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the heads up. My Question was How can I share both at the same time when I call startActivity?

Comment: My main use for the intent is only for sending the intent with the e-mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/10/07/runtime-permissions-files-action-send.html) out and [this](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html) out

A content Uri is all you need. 
There is no need to use a file Uri.

In future other apps may want to avoid READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE which is required to read File Uri's. So you may avoid them.

---

If you just want to share files with different type, use `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`

```
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, yourUriArrayList);
intent.setType("*/*");
```

Comment: Thats what I was looking for.

Comment: @Waffles.Inc No problem. I somehow misunderstood the question.