# How to send audio file from firebase on whatsapp

Tags: android-studio, uri, whatsapp

I have a firebase and few audio files on him, and I have the download url.
I want to send the audio file on whatsapp, how can I do this?

I wrote this:

```
Intent whatsappIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            whatsappIntent.setType("audio/*");
            whatsappIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(audioUrl));
            try {
                context.startActivity(whatsappIntent);
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                //ToastHelper.MakeShortText("Whatsapp have not been installed.");
            }
```

and when I choose who I want to send him I got this error: Failed to share

How can I fix that?

EDIT:

The error said: "Failed to share" and I see it on the screen like toast message.

Comment: Please add more details about the error (is it shown in the screen?, add the catlog with the whole error message). Seems that you're just passing the URL with the intent. Would the Whatsapp app have access to the file via just the web URL (I doubt it since it lives in your firebase instance/account)? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33944944/android-share-intent-extra-stream . Also, have you looked for Whatsapp's documentation on how to send it Intents (sorry, https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/28000012 doesn't seem to have info on audio)?

Comment: The error is just on my screen like toast message. I know that there is an option to send audio but its not working for me. I will try to download the audio file and then send him.